# Uncaught Error: useRecaptcha() is called without provider. while import Checkbox inside script setup tag in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, recaptcha

I want to use ReCAPTCHA for my portfolio website to prevent intended email contact spamming to `EmailJS`, but when I followed the documentations, it show an error `Uncaught Error: useRecaptcha() is called without provider.`

I tried both of with `@unhead/vue` and without `@unhead/vue`

using `@unhead/vue`

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createHead } from '@unhead/vue'
import { VueRecaptchaPlugin } from 'vue-recaptcha'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'


const app = createApp(App)
const head = createHead()
app.use(head)
app.use(VueRecaptchaPlugin, {
  v2SiteKey: import.meta.env.VITE_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY,
})
app.mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<script setup>

import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue'
import Projects from './components/Projects.vue'
import About from './components/About.vue'
import Contact from './components/Contact.vue';

import { useRecaptchaProvider } from 'vue-recaptcha'
useRecaptchaProvider()

</script>

<template>
  <Navbar/>
  <div id="about">
    <About/>
  </div>
  <div id="work-experience">
    Work Experience
  </div>
  <div id="projects">
    <Projects/>
  </div>
  <div id="contact">
    <Contact/>
  </div>
</template>

...
```

Contact.vue

```
<script setup>

import { Checkbox } from 'vue-recaptcha';

</script>

<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="contact">
      <h2>Reach me</h2>
      <div class="social">

      </div>
    </div>
    <form ref="form" @submit.prevent="sendEmail">
      <div class="form">
        <input type="text" name="from_name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="email" name="from_email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" name="company_name" placeholder="Company">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <Checkbox/>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Warning

```
[Vue warn]: injection "Symbol(vue-recaptcha-context)" not found. 
  at <Checkbox> 
  at <Contact> 
  at <App>
```

```
[Vue warn]: [vue-recaptcha]: You may forget to `use` vue-recaptcha plugin 
  at <Checkbox> 
  at <Contact> 
  at <App>
```

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function 
  at <Checkbox> 
  at <Contact> 
  at <App>
```

Error

```
Uncaught Error: useRecaptcha() is called without provider.
    at useRecaptchaContext (context.mjs?v=40414563:8:11)
    at useAssertV2SiteKey (context.mjs?v=40414563:17:15)
    at useChallengeV2 (challenge-v2.mjs?v=40414563:12:19)
    at useComponentV2 (component-v2.mjs?v=40414563:5:83)
    at setup (Checkbox.vue:46:18)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:173:22)
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7265:29)
    at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7220:11)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5542:13)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5517:17)
```

not using `@unhead/vue` is same as using but not create head and change import as `vue-recaptcha/head` Also, I get the same warning and error as using `@unhead/vue`

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. I don't see how it's possible to get this error from this implementation

Comment: My code is already show the way to reproduce, I guess it happen on `<script setup>` tag

Comment: Your problem requires to debug code and reproduce it by users. Providing a way to reproduce a problem is an easy way to get your problem solved. From what I see in lib source code, I'd expect that it's not reproducible, and something wrong happens on your side. You'd possibly could see open issues in lib's repo if this were the case, but there are none

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I looked into package json and I had version 3.0.0 alpha. I think they do something wrong with the versions that you can install. Try if you have the same if so, uninstall the alpha version and install version "2.0.3". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem on when using the vue-recaptcha package version 3.0.0-alpha.2, updating to 3.0.0-alpha.6 fixed it for me.

Update your version number in package.json to the mentioned version above, and run npm install

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).